# AppleScript syntax

Tags: applescript, macos

I know this is sloppy code, but here it is:

```
display dialog ("Start Screensaver. Please type: matrix, coffee, waffles, star, water, or
fireworks.", default answer "")
if text returned of result = "matrix" then
set user_choice to "MatrixSaver"
else
if text returned of result = "coffee" then
    set user_choice to "Coffee"
else
    if text returned of result = "waffles" then
        set user_choice to "Waffles"
    else
        if text returned of result = "star" then
            set user_choice to "Hyperspace"
        else
            if text returned of result = "water" then
                set user_choice to "LotsaWater"
            else
                if text returned of result = "fireworks" then
                    set user_choice to "Skyrocket"
                else
                    (*do nothing*)
                end if
            end if
        end if
    end if
end if
end if

if (user_choice = null) then (*do nothing*)
else
tell application "System Events"
    set ss to screen saver user_choice
    start ss
end tell
end if
```

When I'm trying to compile my code, the 'default answer' Is highlighted, and it says: "Expected “)”, etc. but found identifier."

Any Ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the correct syntax is just

```
display dialog "Start Screensaver. Please ..." default answer ""
```

Answer (score 2):

The `,` between the `("Start Screensaver")` and the `default answer` parameter is causing the syntax error. Remove the `,`.

This isn't a syntax error, but the variable `user_choice` doesn't exist outside of the big `if` block. If you ran it as written, you would get this message at the last `if` block:

> The variable `user_choice` is not defined.

You could fix this by declaring the variable before the `display dialog` statement...

```
set the user_choice to ""
```

Now you can use the variable anywhere in the code. :)

Comment: The second half of your answer is incorrect—AppleScript only has local (function) and global scopes.

Comment: @fireshadow25 When I did what you said, 'default' of 'default answer' was highlighted, and the program say that  it expected a "," Any Thoughts?

Comment: @CodeKid Yeah. The parenthases aren't really needed unless you are evaluating an expression. I'd suggest removing both parentheses from the `display dialog` statement.